# What is this plant? Looks like a brassica, if so, what type?

Tags: identification, brassicas

My mother just bought some flowers, and would like them identifying. She thinks they are brassicas, but would like to know what variety...

[image]

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single species *Brassica oleracea* contains a huge range of different forms grown as food crops, including cabbage, cauliflower, Brussels sprouts, broccoli, kale, kohlrabi, etc.

The ones in your picture are usually called "ornamental cabbage" or "flowering kale." There are many different varieties available with flower colours from purple to white.

They are just as easy to grow as any other types of cabbage, if you want some in your own garden.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would they grow in the UK?

Comment: Sure. Sow the seed in March and plant them outside just like cabbage. They should flower from about June through to December. You can grow them in the ground or in pots or containers. They probably won't grow well indoors though. Cabbage doesn't like high temperatures and some varieties (e.g. Brussels sprouts) will survive being buried in snow over winter.